# Why do we need to convert objects into a Map?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can somebody explain (in simple words please) why we need to convert objects into a `Map`?
I saw below code in medium.com and didn't get it:

```
package com.nayan.examples;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
public class ObjectToMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Student obj = new Student();
        obj.setName("nayan");
        obj.setAge(34);
        obj.setSkills(Arrays.asList("java","angular"));
        // object -> Map
        Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{name=nayan, age=34, skills=[java, angular]}
```

Can't we just put `value` with `key` as it is without any conversion?

Comment: The code you've posted converts an object to a map because that is the point of the code.

Comment: @khelwood I know that but will the output be changed if don't convert the object?

Comment: If you don't want to convert an object into a map, then you don't need to. If you want to know why this specific code converts an object to a map, you should ask the author of this code.

Comment: That is not what I am asking. In order to know whether you need it or not, you need understand advantages/disadvantages of using it (object converter).  @MarkRotteveel

Comment: It's simple: you do this if you need a map instead of an object. If you don't need a map, then you shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code you found is about the concept of **object mapping**. The idea is: you have **java objects** that carry information, and you want to **automatically** turn that *information* into some other format.

Meaning: conceptually, a Student, that is just a collection of key/value pairs, like `name is nayan`.

The essential part here: this code shows you how to turn a Student object into another "format", in this case, a raw Map with key/value pairs.

You mainly want to use that when **persistency** comes into play. Meaning: say you want to store your data as JSON. Do you really want to write all the code *manually* that takes your objects, turns them into a JSON representation, or vice versa? No, you don't (unless for educational purposes).

Comment: Thanks a lot  . I get it now. What really gave me a sense of using object converter is the last paragraph, since I am currently learning Spring Boot.

Comment: @Rahman You are very welcome. In case you find my answer helpful enough, please consider accepting it.